# Replace Headers name in the first row from the cells column of another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to achieve the following automation in VBA. I have different Sheets with wrong headers. I have another sheet called "HeadersMap", which contains the list of all Sheets's correct headers. What I want to do is, if I open a "Sheet1" then the code should go to the "HeadersMap" sheet > check the opened sheet name in the "SheetNames" column > check the Original header in "OriginalHeaders" column and copy correct header name from the "Correct Headers" column and replace the headers in the "Sheet1".  And similarly , if I open "Sheet2", it should do the same.

"SHEET1"

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aplpe | baanann | Roange |
| 2 |  |  |  |
| 3 |  |  |  |

SHEET "HEADERSMAP"

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SheetNames | OriginalHeaders | CorrectHeaders |
| 2 | Sheet1 | aplpe | Apple |
| 3 | Sheet1 | baanann | Banana |
| 4 | Sheet1 | Roange | Orange |
| 5 | Sheet2 | sgura | Sugar |
| 6 | Sheet2 | Jggaery | Jaggery |
| 7 | Sheet3 | Dtergetn | Detergent |
| 8 | Sheet3 | poas | Soap |
| 9 | Sheet3 | Lfua | Lufa |

Desired Result "SHEET1"

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple | Banana | Orange |
| 2 |  |  |  |
| 3 |  |  |  |

Comment: When the sheet is created, or when (each time) the sheet is selected?

Comment: @ChristoferWeber When I import this "Sheet1" in the Workbook which contains the Sheet "HeadersMap". So there are different sheets like.. Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3,etc. which has wrong headers. I want to to Select the Sheet1 when it is imported and compare the headers name from "HeaderMaps" , replace the names and save the Sheet1 with correct headers!

Comment: So you have a workbook with the "HeadersMaps" sheet, and then you import a new sheet from another workbook? And if it's called "Sheet1", we should look for Sheet1 in HeadersMaps and replace the headers, and so on for Sheet2 or whatever, as long as the name exists in the HeadersMaps? Do we care about the OriginalHeaders at all, or just copy the CorrectHeaders into the sheet?

Comment: @ChristoferWeber Yes exactly. And we don't care about the OriginalHeaders at all, need to copy the correctHeaders into the Sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
Sub test()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim vDB As Variant
    Dim rngHeader As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    
    Set Ws = Sheets("HEADERSMAP")
    
    vDB = Ws.Range("a1").CurrentRegion
    
    For i = 2 To UBound(vDB, 1)
        If isHas(vDB(i, 1)) Then
            Set Ws = Sheets(vDB(i, 1))
            Set rngHeader = Ws.Rows(1)
            rngHeader.Replace vDB(i, 2), vDB(i, 3)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
Function isHas(v As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    For Each Ws In Worksheets
        If Ws.Name = v Then
            isHas = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next Ws
End Function
```

Comment: In my workbook which contains the Sheets "Sheet1" and "HeadersMap" opened. I tried the code but it throws an error "Subsript out of range" and stops at "Set Ws = Sheets(vDB(i, 1))"

Comment: The code now works! What I am trying to make it work for the existing sheets also. Like I mentioned to Christofer and VBasic2008 , I want to specify the Sheet name. Let's say Sheet("Fruits").

Comment: Your code satisfied the question of this problem though! Thanks a lot for your precious contribution! Kind Regards

Answer (score 1):

### Correct Headers

**Edit**

- After reading your comment, it may be best to copy the complete code to the `ThisWorkbook` module (if you insist on this functionality). There is no need for adding another module.

---

- It is assumed that the data in worksheet `HeadersMap` starts in cell `A1`.

**Standard Module e.g. `Module1`**

```
Option Explicit

Sub correctHeaders(ws As Worksheet)
    
    Const sName As String = "HeadersMap"
    Const sFirst As String = "A1"
    
    Dim rg As Range
    Dim Data As Variant
    
    Set rg = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sName).Range(sFirst).CurrentRegion
    If IsNumeric(Application.Match(ws.Name, rg.Columns(1), 0)) Then
    
        Data = rg.Value
        
        Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        Dim Result() As Variant
        Dim r As Long, j As Long
        For r = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
            If StrComp(Data(r, 1), ws.Name, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                j = j + 1
                ReDim Preserve Result(1 To 2, 1 To j)
                Result(1, j) = Data(r, 2)
                Result(2, j) = Data(r, 3)
            End If
        Next r
        
        If j > 0 Then
            Set rg = ws.UsedRange.Rows(1)
            Data = rg.Value
            Dim cIndex As Variant
            For j = 1 To j
                cIndex = Application.Match(Result(1, j), Data, 0)
                If IsNumeric(cIndex) Then
                    Data(1, cIndex) = Result(2, j)
                End If
            Next j
            rg.Value = Data
        End If
    
    End If

End Sub
```

**Additional Functionality (you have to run it)**

```
Sub correctHeadersApply
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws in Thisworkbook.Worksheets
        correctHeaders ws
    Next ws
End Sub
```

**`ThisWorkbook` Module**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    correctHeaders ActiveSheet
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    If Sh.Type = xlWorksheet Then
        correctHeaders Sh
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I copied the Standard Module as Module1 and also the "Sub correctHeadersApply". Also copied "Private Sub Workbook_Open()" and "Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)" to ThisWorkbook. I get no errors but the code does not do anything!

Comment: Have you tried to run the `correctHeadersApply` procedure? Does the data in worksheet `HeadersMap` start in cell `A1` (`SheetNames`)? It has to start in `A1`, or you have to find another way to define the range (`rg`).

Comment: The code works. It was not working for the existing Sheets. Because of the code is in ThisWorkbook module and when I create or import new sheets, the code works! Can we not put the code in ThisWorkbook module and run it manually for specific sheets whether newly imported or existing? Let's say, there is already a Sheet named "Fruits" , and I want to correct headers, so I simply run the code, select the Sheet "Fruits" and correct the headers. Where should I add sheet "Fruits" in the code? Thanks

Comment: You can use the code from `Workbook_SheetActivate` in the same event that Christofer Weber used in his answer: `Workbook_NewSheet`, to automate the renaming. If you want to 'manually' rename headers in a worksheet, create a new `Sub` e.g. containing the single line `correctHeaders ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Fruits")` and run it. Also, you could rather use `correctHeaders ActiveSheet` (I guess the latter is what you're looking for).

Comment: I did it and work great! Thanks a lot for your precious contribution! :) Kind Regards

Answer (score 1):

Bare minimum would probably be putting this in ThisWorkbook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)
Dim targetRange As Range, i As Long
Set targetRange = Worksheets("HEADERSMAP").Range("A1:A9")
i = 1
    For Each entry In targetRange
        If entry.Value = Sh.NAME Then
            Sh.Cells(1, i) = entry.Offset(, 2).Value
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

If the data is looking like your examples.
Later you might want ot change `Range("A1:A9")` to look for the last row, and `Offset(, 2)` to maybe `Offset(, 1)` since the "OriginalHeaders" column is superflous in reality.

The Module version would be something like:

```
Sub headers()
Dim targetRange As Range, i As Long, Sh As Worksheet
Set Sh = Worksheets(InputBox("Enter name of sheet"))
Set targetRange = Worksheets("HEADERSMAP").Range("A1:A9")
i = 1
    For Each entry In targetRange
        If entry.Value = Sh.NAME Then
            Sh.Cells(1, i) = entry.Offset(, 2).Value
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

That is if the name of the sheet and the item in the list correlate.
You could set a second variable with a second inputbox, and replace `Sh.NAME` to select from the list manually.
Like so:

```
Sub headers()
Dim targetRange As Range, i As Long, Sh As Worksheet, name As String
Set Sh = Worksheets(InputBox("Enter name of sheet"))
name = InputBox("Enter name from map")
Set targetRange = Worksheets("HEADERSMAP").Range("A1:A9")
i = 1
    For Each entry In targetRange
        If entry.Value = name Then
            Sh.Cells(1, i) = entry.Offset(, 2).Value
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Then you can manually type witch sheet get what headers, if you like to do that.

Comment: The code works perfectly! But the problem is with the sheet numbers. For eg. after updating the Sheet1, I save it and delete it. And I keep deleting the sheets from the workbook when they are updated. After deleting 3 sheets then I import a new sheet, excel will consider it as Sheet4 and it is not in the HeadersMap. And, I don't want to put the code in ThisWorkbook Module, I want to put it in standard module. Let's say I import Sheet named "Fruits" then I run this code and select Sheet "Fruit" and replace headers from "HeaderMaps" I want to put the sheet name in the code!

Comment: @Goku Should be easy to remake. As soon as I get back to my computer. Unless the other answer is fine.

Comment: Wait, if you import fruits, and fruit is there, it would work. Does it import as Sheetx anyway? Do you want to rename the sheet, and then run the code? Or how exactly do want i to work?

Comment: Made a little edit. I mean, you can go further, and do dropdowns and whatnot.

Comment: Finally, everything is working! Thanks a lot for your precious contribution! Kind Regards